# Guardar en un solo arreglo valores generados dinamicamente por un ciclo

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy realizando una especie de tabla de ajedrez para poder realizar un ejercicio sobre posicionar reinas en el tablero y si está correcto las posiciones de cada reina (que no se "coman" o capturen) está correcto.

Por ahora el programa detecta las reinas que se comen en la posiciones 1 (adjuntare todo el codigo para que lo vean) el problema es que no logro guardar en un solo array las reinas para poder comparar y decir si se comen o no.

```
    <table border="1" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0">
    <?php for ($x = 0; $x < 7; $x++): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php for ($y = 0; $y < 7; $y++): ?>
                <td id="<?php echo $y . '.' . $x ?>" data-value="<?php echo $y . '.' . $x ?>"></td>
            <?php endfor ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endfor ?>
</table>

<script>

    // El 1 representa la pieza dama o reina en el ajedrez


    function posit(a, b)
    {   

        arr = new Array();

        conc = a + '.' + b;

        document.getElementById(conc).innerHTML = '1';
        x = 0;
        y = 0;

        while (x <= 6 && y <= 6) {

            if (x >= 0 && x <= 6 && y >= 0 && y <= 6) {

                arr[x] = x + '.' + y;
                x++;
                if (x == 7 && y >= 0 && y <= 6) {

                    x = 0;
                    y += 1;
                }                   
            }
            if (b == 1 && arr[x] == conc) {

                datos = conc.split(" ");
                console.log(datos); // Me muestra 3 arreglos distintos con valores diferentes, necesito que se guarde en 1 solo arreglo todos los elementos
            }
        }
    }

    var reina = new Array(

        posit(6,1),
        posit(4,1),
        posit(5,1),
    );

</script>
```

Comment: Cuando haces `split` se crea un array. ¿No deberías tener un array independiente al cual vayas metiendo el valor de `conc` sin hacer `split`? Algo como: `arrayFinal.push(conc);`

Comment: Le quite el split y use push. Aun me sigue creando 3 arrays distintos en vez de uno